# remove disabled property from a html object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I am adding html on my page on click of a button.So when i adding the html i want to remove all the disabled property from the html variable so that the new html don't have any disabled inputs :

**Code:**

```
var current_td = $(thisobj).closest('tr').html();
    var next_td = $(thisobj).closest('tr').siblings('tr.add').html();
    var added1 = '<tr class="class2">'+current_td+'</tr>';
    var added2 = '<tr class="class1">'+next_td+'</tr>';
    var main_html = added1 + added2;
    main_html = main_html.replace("Add[+]" ,"Remove [-]");
    $('#create_table').append("<tbody id=TBody"+Count+">"+main_html+"</tbody>");
    masterCodeCount++;
    return "TBody"+(Count-1);
```

From **main_html** variable i want to remove the disabled property of the inputs types.Because from where i am getting the html the inputs type are disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
var current_td = $(thisobj).closest('tr').html();
var next_td = $(thisobj).closest('tr').siblings('tr.add').html();
var added1 = '<tr class="class2">' + current_td + '</tr>';
var added2 = '<tr class="class1">' + next_td + '</tr>';
var main_html = added1 + added2;
main_html = main_html.replace("Add[+]", "Remove [-]");
var $main = $(main_html);
//remove the disabled attribute
$main.find(':disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
$("<tbody id=TBody" + Count + "></tbody>").append($main).appendTo('#create_table');
masterCodeCount++;
return "TBody" + (Count - 1);
```

Comment: $(main_html).find(':disabled').removeAttr('disabled'); this is not working

Comment: @Gaurav it is `$main.find(':disabled').removeAttr('disabled');` with `var $main = $(main_html);` before it and `$main` is used to append the content not `main_html`